# convert json data in key value by jolt processor

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I have following Input and i want to convert the data in expected output by jolt  processor

**Input**

```json
{
  "tenantId": "master",
  "transactionId": "838",
  "alertArray": [
    {
      "alertType": "info",
      "priority": "low",
      "data": "new",
      "properties": [
        {
          "ConnectorID": "1",
          "ConnectorType": "IEC_60309",
          "IDTag": "A5270529",
          "abc": "xyz",
          "pqr": "rst",
          "bals": "ahjdgcd"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected output**

```json
{
  "tenantId": "master",
  "transactionId": "838",
  "alertArray": [
    {
      "alertType": "info",
      "priority": "low",
      "data": "new",
      "properties": [
        {
          "key": "ConnectorID",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "key": "ConnectorType",
          "value": "IEC_60309"
        },
        {
          "key": "DTag",
          "value": "A5270529"
        },
        {
          "key": "abc",
          "value": "xyz"
        },
        {
          "key": "pqr",
          "value": "rst"
        },
        {
          "key": "bals",
          "value": "ahjdgcd"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

we have data that contain properties array properties array contain pair of data and i want to convert the pair of data into key and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **shift** transformation after diving deep into the attributes under `properties` array and use **`@`** and **`$`** symbols to match val and key pairs respectively

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "alertA*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&", //&2 is to substitute "alertArray" after going tree 2 levels up along with its indexes([&1]), and the rightmost & is replicates the current level's values 
          "pro*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "$": "&5[&4].&3[#2].key", // &5 : "alertArray", [&4] : indexes of "alertArray", &3 : "properties", indexes of "properties"
                "@": "&5[&4].&3[#2].value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: You're welcome @Neeraj , best wishes...

Comment: Barbaros you have mension &4 = index of alertArray I want to understand how it is happening . can you please help me to understand it or can you please suggest any document or any tutorial to understand it

Comment: Sure @Neeraj . There are some tutorials, and blogs which I like such as [1](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt) , [2](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases), [3](https://erbalvindersingh.medium.com/applying-jolttransform-on-json-object-array-and-fetching-specific-fields-48946870b4fc), [4](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3159219-transformer-operations-overview), [5](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3096940-simple-if-else-with-jolt). Good luck!